# Segmented Control inside a TableView

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol, custom-cell

I've spent hours trying to find a solution but I always end up with nothing.

I am trying to create a Segment Control inside a `TableView` that have a `CustomCell` for two views for the Segment Control.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dw7kytoA3KU&t=198s is a perfect example of what I am trying to accomplish but the user puts inserts 1 CustomCell and the code is a bit confusing.

My first CustomCell contains an images, names, and numbers.
My second CustomCell contains only an image.

So my questions is...

1. How should I create two array for the two CustomCell?

   *Example of what I'm trying to accomplish*

Custom Cell 1:

```
              let names = ["Pizza","Soup","Tacos","Chicken", "Beef"]
              let image = [UIImage(named: "Pizza1"), UIImage(named: "Soup1"), UIImage(named: "Tacos1"), UIImage(named: "Chicken1"), UIImage(named: "Beef1")]
              let numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Custom Cell 2:

```
          let photo = [UIImage(named: "Pic1"), UIImage(named: "Pic2"), UIImage(named: "Pic3")]
```

2. From what I've researched, When it's time to call for the CustomCell file and the two CustomCell into my code, would this be correct?

   ```
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(nib, forCallReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell1")
    tableView.register(nib, forCallReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell2")
   ```
3. What should be returned for this?

   `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`
4. This part is where I get confused on what to enter

   `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Summary: I'm trying to create a segment control in a tableView that have 2 CustomCells. I want the first view of the segment to be CustomCell that has the images, name, and number. The second view of the segment to have just the image.

Thanks!

Comment: A TableView... inside... a segment control?

Comment: @Matthew ...my bad, a UISegmented Control in a Tableview

Answer (score 0):

> How should I create two array for the two CustomCell?

```
let names = ["Pizza","Soup","Tacos","Chicken", "Beef"]
let image = [UIImage(named: "Pizza1"), UIImage(named: "Soup1"), UIImage(named: "Tacos1"), UIImage(named: "Chicken1"), UIImage(named: "Beef1")]
let numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
```

Having three arrays would work, but is a little strange. A Swift struct and one array might be easier to work with:

```
struct Food {
  var name: String
  var image: UIImage
  var number: Int
}

let foods = [
  Food(name: "Pizza", image: UIImage(named: "Pizza1"), number: 1),
  Food(name: "Soup", image: UIImage(named: "Soup1"), number: 2),
  Food(name: "Tacos", image: UIImage(named: "Tacos1"), number: 3),
  Food(name: "Chicken", image: UIImage(named: "Chicken1"), number: 4),
  Food(name: "Beef", image: UIImage(named: "Beef1"), number: 5)
]
```

> From what I've researched, When it's time to call for the CustomCell file and the two CustomCell into my code, would this be correct?

```
let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib, forCallReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell1")
tableView.register(nib, forCallReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell2")
```

Almost... if you have two custom cells, I'd expect to see two nibs:

```
let nib1 = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell1", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib1, forCallReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell1")
let nib2 = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell2", bundle: nil)
tableView.register(nib2, forCallReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell2")
```

> What should be returned for this?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

That the number of cells in your table. So it might be:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  return foods.count
}
```

> This part is where I get confused on what to enter

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

This is where your app *dequeues* a cell, and configures its contents prior to it appearing in the table:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell1", for: indexPath)
  cell.nameLabel.text = foods[indexPath.row].name
  return cell
}
```

I'm still not sure what you intend to do with SegmentedControls... do you want each cell to contain a segmented control? That would be quite... unusual.

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you run through some tutorials on how to use UITableViews and UISegmentedControl as it looks like you are a beginner in iOS development. Now to answer your questions:

```
#1. How should I create two array for the two CustomCell?
```

I suggest you study creating NSObjects in Swift. Using this you can set the properties such as name, images, numbers, etc on your object. Then you can have a collection of your objects and use them on your data source for your table.

```
#2. Regarding Custom UITableViewCells.
```

Yes you will need to register your custom UITableViewCells for you to use them. Or do the storyboard way.

```
#3. func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

You specify in this delegate method the number of rows that should appear in your UITableView. For example, if you have an array of your food objects you would return foods.count.

```
#4. func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

This is the part where you create and customize the cell that will be shown on the rows of your UITableView.

If you want a UITableView and UISegmentedControl together, I suggest going the easiest way by adding a UISegmentedControl and two UITableViews on the view of your UIViewController. Change the visible UITableView depending on which segment is selected, you can catch it on the value change event of the UISegmentedControl.